# How can I export the Contacts of my Contacts2.db to the Emulator's Contacts in Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, contacts, ddms

I took a backup of Contacts2.db from my android phone. I have an application where I can see all of my contacts in an Activity.

Instead of adding contact by contact to have more number of contacts in my emulator, I replaced the Contacts2.db of the Emulator with my db using DDMS Perspective in Eclipse.

I shutdown and started my Emulator to see the contacts. While the Emulator is getting started, I can see the Contacts2.db size equal to Phone's Contacts2.db size. But after rebooting completely it is replaced with the default Contacts.db. Now I am not able to access my phone's Contacts.db.

I tried the same thing with mmssms.db. I am able to see all of my SMS in emulator.

So I want my phone's contacts to be seen in my Emulator. Is there any other way is also appreciated ?

Comment: instead of shutting down, did you just kill the contacts provider and contacts app

Comment: But no help.. still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have an sd card image attached to ur emulator you can backup all your working contacts to a vcard which you can import later anytime, even extract the vcf file and import in another emulator.

The menu option is in Contacts->Menu->Manage Contacts->Back up

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've solved this, but you might want to make sure that you have unchecked the 'Launch from snapshot' checkbox when starting the AVD.